# Postfix - specify interface to deliver outbound mail on

Tags: postfix

I need to be able to specify what interface Postfix will use to deliver outbound mail on.  What I am doing is setting up an SMTP gateway to deliver mail from different, unrelated groups.  I plan to setup a separate instance of Postfix for each group to receive mail, and each instance will need to deliver on its own virtual interface.

The reason I need them separate is so that if one of the groups misbehaves and gets the server blacklisted, I don't want any of the other groups affected.  But I don't want to have to setup entirely separate servers or VMs if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for `smtp_bind_address` and `smtp_bind_address6`. Details are available [here.](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_bind_address)

Comment: It's customary when the answer is correct to click the little tick mark next to the answer! People are more likely to answer future questions if you acknowledge previous correct answers!

Answer (score 1):

Would [`inet_interfaces`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces) do what you want?

> When inet_interfaces specifies just
>   one IPv4 and/or IPv6 address that is
>   not a loopback address, the **Postfix
>   SMTP client will use this address as
>   the IP source address for outbound
>   mail**. Support for IPv6 is available
>   in Postfix version 2.2 and later.